# IIS6 with ASP MVC Wildcard mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, wildcard

Ok, so Im one of the 100's of people having issues getting ASP MVC running on IIS6.

I have followed several tutorials including [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) and [this](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/), but still no joy. All I see is the standard IE 404 file not found page.

Now in order to ensure that my site is pointing to the correct location I have added a stub index.html file in the root dir. When I navigate to this file I get the 404 error, BUT if I turn off wildcard mapping for all urls through aspnet_isapi.dll then I CAN navigate to the index file.

So my question basically is, what gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are not checking the "verify that file exists" button on the wildcard mapping.

Then make sure you have a Default.aspx file in the root of your web with this code in it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
}
```

Comment: Yup, thats unchecked, and I have a default.aspx in the root. Although it was the one generated by the VS project and has a few more lines of code than your example. Ill try altering this, but as I said, Im having issues with a simple index.html test file.

Comment: Doh, well the answer was simple in my case. I thought the .NET 3.5 sp1 contained the MVC stuff but its a separate download.